# why can't I take input while debugging in VS code?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, input, terminal

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
   int a,b,c;
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
    printf("%d\n",c);

return 0;
}
```

this is my simple program. my terminal does not take input while I am in debugging mode. here I am attaching my launch.json setting.[image]

I can take input in terminal when I am not in debugging mode. This problem accours when I am debugging a program. I have set my "externalConsole": true, but its not working afterall.

Comment: While debugging meaning, you have set breakpoints? Are you stepping over your lines at that time?

Comment: I have set my breakpoint before the scanf function.

Comment: So the control is waiting there. It hasn't reached to scanf yet. Hence you cant take input at this time